# IE 10 removes url parameters

Tags: internet-explorer, redirect

I am opening this url:

```
http://localhost:8080/plan/index?topic=Hadoop&planId=70315
```

it works fine in google chrome,but ie 10 redirects to `http://localhost:8080/plan`

I am using jquery and knockout js,is that causing problem ?

I don't know what's happening,please help me figure this out.

Comment: any server side code?

Comment: using grails on server side and doing `render(view:'myview')`

Comment: looks like,IE is doing that after a ajax call.any reason ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using html5 history api which was not supported by IE.removing the statndard html5 history api and using History.js solved the problem